# Monoprice Select Mini v2 clogged Boden tube connection

Tags: monoprice-select-mini, ptfe-tube

I have had my Monoprice Select Mini v2 for about two weeks now and I get a clicking noise on my filament insert on some prints and when I check a few minutes later, I can see that it's not extruding and that there is a clog of some sort.

I checked to see whethere there was possibly a clog in my hot end or nozzle, but there was nothing there. So I checked my Boden tube to see if the filament was brittle and had broken, but I found that there was plastic with a slight twist clogged in the Boden tube connector. When it first happened I had used an Allen wrench to push the plastic out. The second time it was harder and took heating the connector piece up to melt the plastic and pull it out.

Now I know (from the ticking) that my gear feeder is making a clicking noise - as it did when it was clogged. So when I hear that, I just push the lever to loosen it and it sounds like it releases tension. So is there a way to stop this or prevent it? I tried upping the temperature on the nozzle but it didn't help much. I'm printing from an average of 60°C and a high of 80°C with PLA.

Answer (score 3):

If you are heating your hotend to 60/80, that is *WAY* too low. PLA should be at 180+ hotend, and if you are using a heated bed, 60-80.

I would try increasing the heat of your hotend, starting at 180 and increasing if it looks like it is underextruding or if you get more clogs.